# Redirect all subdomains to a new root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.2

I am looking to change a root domain of a site.

The domain in question has several sub domains as aliases.

I would like to use htaccess to redirect the sub domains to the new domain:

eg :

```
test.domain1.com > test.domain2.com
```

Looking around I can see that the condition I need is as follows :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

But I cannot see what the RewriteRule should be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect `test.subdomain.com` to `test.subdomain2.com` you can use the following Rule :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domin2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: This redirects all subdomains to one. I want to reroute to whatever subdomain was requested

Answer (score 2):

Here's the *correct* way to do it:

> **Remember:** Replace `example.com`, and `example\.com` below, with your ***own*** domain
>   name.

For `HTTPS://` protocol:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([^.]+)\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

For `HTTP://` protocol:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([^.]+)\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

@starkeen's answer doesn't account for domains with *no sub-domain at all* (e.g. simply, 'https://example.com').

Comment: Thanks alot, works excellent on Gentoo without any extra useflags needed. +1 :)